# Create WPF ellipse from C# code and move it by mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have  a canvas, and I need to put an (for example) ellipse on it, not from XAML but from code. So I do

```
Ellipse e1;

public MainWindow()
    {
        ...
        ... 
        e1 = new Ellipse();
        e1.Height = 100;
        e1.Width = 100;
        e1.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        e1.StrokeThickness = 5;
        Canvas.SetLeft(e1,40);
        Canvas.SetTop(e1,50);
        e1.MouseDown += ellipse_MouseDown;
        Canvas1.Children.Add(e1);

    }

   private void ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse el = (Ellipse)sender;
        el.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
        buttonAdd.Content = "New_TEXT";

    }
```

But it doesn't react on clicking. Anyway, I tried to add this `ellipse_MouseDown`method to ellipse that was created from XAML - and it works.

```
 <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="421" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="346">
      <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="111" Margin="117,152,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131" MouseDown="ellipse_MouseDown" MouseMove="ellipse_MouseMove" MouseUp="ellipse_MouseUp"/>
  </Canvas>
```

Where can be a problem?

**UPD.**

According to Rohit Vats's answer just add

```
e1.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;

or

e1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter
                                       .ConvertFromString("#FFF4F4F5"));
```

'cause by default `Fill` is null which doesn't respond to mouse events

Comment: Please show the XAML that works, so we can compare it with the code that doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Fill` to `Transparent` so that it can react to mouse events. By default `Fill` is `null` which doesn't respond to mouse events -

```
e1.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
e1.Fill = Brushes.Transparent; <-- HERE
```

**UPDATE**

As evident from XAML code, you are setting `Fill` to #`FFF4F4F5` but not setting it from code behind.

```
e1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter
                                       .ConvertFromString("#FFF4F4F5"));
```

Comment: Great. I have update with `Fill` color in case you don't want it to be transparent. Hope it resolves your query. :)